# Anyone else is having this issue here in the web? (really annoying)

Tags: discussion

This had happened to me several times and I can't figure out why.
When I hit de "post your question" button the red error cta appears no matter what I do and with no other explanation but "error ocurred"
Weird thing is that my posts are being published, but i have to refresh the page to see them...

[image: annoying s**t]

Comment: It would be nice if the message said what to do (if there is something to do, or if not maybe a "try in some minutes") to accomplish the goal :)

Comment: I had something similar when posting an answer, several seconds later it was fine again.

Comment: I've had this happen to me off and on for the last few days, too. I can't tell you why, and I have no idea if your problem is the same as the one's I've been having, but I can tell you that for me these issues always go away if I reload the page. So you could highlight your post and copy it to the clipboard (just in case), reload page, paste it and try again.

Comment: This is the most useless of useless titles. Give it a sensible title, fix your spelling errors, and retag it as [tag:bug] instead of [tag:discussion]. This will bring it to the attention of the developers, who can fix the issue.